# How to put some space between <li> elements?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

[image: screenshot of the site]

I want to add more space between Home, About and other buttons. At least about 5px.

Here're my HTML and CSS codes:

```css
.custom-padding{
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  
nav {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ededf1;
    box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #8e8e91, 
                 -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
  }
  
  .menu-area li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ededf1;
    box-shadow:  3px 3px 5px #8e8e91, 
                 -3px -3px 5px #ffffff;
  }
  
  .menu-area a { 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8c93a4;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>
      some title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div class="custom-padding">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">Form</div>
  
        <ul class="menu-area">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So why  not add margin?

Comment: margin doesn't work well here, it adds space to the bottom

Comment: or just makes buttons long or high, I need to add space between them, not make 'em bigger

Comment: `margin-left: 5px` seems to work fine for me

Comment: Assuming you remove the default margin/padding on the `ul`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is margin. I don't know why you did not do that.

```
  .menu-area li {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #ededf1;
      box-shadow:  3px 3px 5px #8e8e91, -3px -3px 5px #ffffff;
      margin: 0px 5px;      // right, left margin of five
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I fixed it:

```css
  .menu-area li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ededf1;
    box-shadow:  3px 3px 5px #8e8e91, 
                 -3px -3px 5px #ffffff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add :

```
.menu-area li{margin: 0 5px";}
```

if the Buttons get bigger, just reduce paddings of your links like:

```
 .menu-area li a{padding: 0 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple.
Use `&nbsp;`.

```css
.custom-padding{
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  
nav {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ededf1;
    box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #8e8e91, 
                 -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
  }
  
  .menu-area li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ededf1;
    box-shadow:  3px 3px 5px #8e8e91, 
                 -3px -3px 5px #ffffff;
  }
  
  .menu-area a { 
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8c93a4;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>
      some title
    </title>
  </head>
  <body >

    <div class="custom-padding">
      <nav>
        <div class="logo">Form</div>
  
        <ul class="menu-area">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/BaNGyVo
Or use `margin`.

```css
.custom-padding{
        padding-top: 25px;
      }
      
    nav {
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #ededf1;
        box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #8e8e91, 
                     -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
        position: relative;
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 2%;
      }
      
.menu-area li {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: #ededf1;
      box-shadow:  3px 3px 5px #8e8e91, -3px -3px 5px #ffffff;
      margin: 0px 5px;
  }
      
      .menu-area a { 
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #8c93a4;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        text-transform: capitalize;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 30px;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>
          some title
        </title>
      </head>
      <body >

        <div class="custom-padding">
          <nav>
            <div class="logo">Form</div>
      
            <ul class="menu-area">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/xxGQbJa

Answer (score -1):

This would work

```
<li style="padding-right:5px"></li>
```

Comment: it makes button bigger, maybe I should to add it not to the <li>? idk